# How to show the message when there are no posts in user feed in react redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, conditional-rendering

Right now, if I go to my feed where the lists of posts is shown. So, when there is no post made, I want to show **No posts found** message. I'm getting `isFetching` and `posts` through `mapStateToProps`.

`posts` is an array field in the reducer, and it's intial state is empty. So, when no posts are made, the array is empty.

How do I show the message though?

````js
  render() {
    const { isFetching, posts  } = this.props

    return isFetching ? (
      <p>Fetching....</p>
    ) : (
      <div>
        {posts &&
          posts.map((post) => {
            return <Cards key={post._id} post={post} />
          })}
      </div>
    )
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you're checking `isFetching`, but instead use `posts.length != 0`.

```
return isFetching ? (
    <p>Fetching....</p>
) : (
    <div>
        {(posts && posts.length != 0) ?
            posts.map((post) => { 
                return <Cards key={post._id} post={post} />
            }) : <p>No posts found</p>}
    </div> 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [condition operators](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) in this case.

```
return isFetching ? (
      <p>Fetching....</p>
    ) : (
      <div>
        { posts 
            ? ( 
                posts.map((post) => {
                return <Cards key={post._id} post={post} />
               ): (
               <div> No posts found</div>
               )
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` else to render based on your requirement.

```js
render() {
  const { isFetching, posts } = this.props

  if (isFetching) {
    return <p>Fetching...</p>;
  } else if (!posts && posts.length) {
    return <p>No posts found</p>
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        {posts.map(post => <Cards key={post._id} post={post} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Note: Ternary can also be used but I guess, `if` would look much readable here.